# does 2^2n implies 2^n?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am learning algorithm analysis. In a book I read that 2^2n = O(2^n) is not true. though I know that means we can't find a c such that : 2^2n<=c(2^n). but if we put n=5 and c=10^6 the equation will be right. can you please give me hint. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example only works when n is small, consider all n where n goes to infinity.

Comment: You need to find a c for f(n) = c*2^n that makes f(n) > 2^n *for all* n (larger than some minimum, which you can choose/imply).

Comment: You need to look up the definition of big O, and apply it. You are currently using your own inaccurate definition of big O.

Answer (score 2):

For 2^2n = O(2^n) to hold you would have to find one c such that 2^2n<=c(2^n) for all n > n0. Your example works only for small n. Once n reaches a point where 2^n > c the inequality does no longer hold.

Answer (score 2):

Let's just work out the math: `2^2n = (2^2)^n = 4^n`, since `a^bc = (a^b)^c`.

The question is not what happens for specific values, but what is the effect when `n` gets one larger, or even twice as large.

If we replace `n` with `n + 1`, you get `2^2(n + 1) = 2^(2n + 2) = 2^2 * 2^2n = 4 * 2^2n`. So the result becomes 4 times larger.

Comment: yeah guess I had a wrong understanding about Big o.